# How to get data from memory address (python)

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

I am not familiar in memory management. 
What I am going to do is want to read data in memory address. I search about how to get the memory address of process and get the base address.

1. get the pid of process

   ```
   def get_pid(process_name):
       for proc in psutil.process_iter():
           if process_name in str(proc.name):
               print ("target: {}, pid: {}".format(process_name, proc.pid))
               return proc.pid
   ```
2. find base address of process

   ```
   process = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, False, pid)
   modules = win32process.EnumProcessModules(process)
   print(hex(modules))
   ```

> result:
>
> 0x140000000 0x7ff972560000 0x7ff96b650000 0x7ff971d90000
>   0x7ff96eb70000 0x7ff96cb60000 0x7ff950ee0000 0x7ff971e50000
>   0x7ff971fd0000 0x7ff970f30000 0x7ff9721f0000 0x7ff972500000
>   0x7ff96f0e0000 0x7ff96f040000 0x7ff96edf0000 0x7ff9718d0000
>   0x7ff96f020000 0x7ff9724d0000 0x7ff96cb30000 0x7ff96cad0000
>   0x7ff96e930000 0x7ff96efa0000 0x7ff9723a0000 0x7ff9715a0000
>   0x7ff9720e0000 0x7ff970ed0000 0x7ff96fa90000 0x7ff96f2e0000
>   0x7ff96e8f0000 0x7ff96e8d0000 0x7ff96e870000 0x7ff96e8c0000
>   0x7ff9713e0000 0x7ff971f00000 ...

In this step, I will get a list of modules, len of modules is 137, I assume that is dynamic memory address, is there any way to prove that is dynamic memory?

3. read data in address

   ```
   for module in modules:
       print(hexlify(ctypes.string_at(id(addr), sys.getsizeof(addr))))
   ```

> result:
>   b'0100000000000000902c806c000000000b00000000000000ffffffffffffffffe4323038380000000000000000000000307831343030303030303000'
>   b'0100000000000000902c806c000000000e00000000000000ffffffffffffffffe4000000000000000000000000000000307837666639373235363030303000'
>   b'0100000000000000902c806c000000000e00000000000000ffffffffffffffffe4323038380000000000000000000000307837666639366236353030303000'
>   ...

How can I get a readable data? Many Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "readable"?

What does the data you are looking for look like?

Comment: @cha0site I am not sure what data is in these memory. But if I press keyboard "V" in a program, It contain "V" in the memory address, is it?

Comment: Probably, yeah. But there's lots of other stuff there, too. Also, things like ASLR mean that the memory address where that `V` shows up might change every time you run the program. If you're hoping to just read memory and find the thing you're looking for, be aware that your looking for a needle in a haystack. You should probably first load the program you're interested in in a debugger, and do some research on how it lays out its memory.

Comment: It's better not to mix *ctypes* with *pywin32*. What do you mean by "*readable data*" (or "*dynamic memory*")? Also you got a list of *HMODULE*s (which are the *.dll*s base addresses). What are you going to do with them? You need to know the format, and so on. It's the same as looking at a *.dll* file with a text editor. Your process memory will probably contain millions of `V`s. Better use *CheatEngine* to get familiar (practically).